# Is it safe to include a javascript file in a template's php file?

Tags: jquery, templates, javascript, page-template, template-include

I want to include some jquery plugin files to my wordpress multisite install. My solution involved creating a specific template file for the pages that required these jquery plugins. Below is the line of code that includes my javascript file which I have placed at the last line of the template file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/plugins/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" ></script>
```

Is this solution a safe way to include files in specific templates?
Any feedback would be very helpful!

Comment: There's nothing dangerous about adding a JS script as long as it doesn't include any sensitive information. JS is fully exposed to client, you shouldn't do it anyway. Just make sure that `src` resolves and you don't expose any back-end code to front-end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @N00b mentioned Yes, it is safe adding a JS script as long as it doesn't include any sensitive information. JS is fully exposed to client, you shouldn't do it anyway.

But your situtaion it is better to create a site specific custom plugin and add JS using it.

Example :

```
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'core', 'style.css', false ); 
}

function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```

More Details : [Plugin API/Action Reference/wp enqueue scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)